# Meteor DDP issues over VPN

Tags: meteor, vpn, ddp

I use VPN to connect to my dev environment in a private cloud.

I have 2 Meteor-based sites running and I can't see the data when I try to connect through the VPN. The site loads but the data is missing.

I use websocket for another API server and it works fine, so my guess is it something wrong with DDP.

Does anybody have any advice on how to troubleshoot this issue?
Thanks